# Searching by zip code and Email Blast error

Tags: massemailmessage, search-layout

I have couple of question for which i need help.

1.How should I add zip code Filter in GLOBAL UI SEARCH. so that I can search for named Accounts by zip code. 
For example I want to do a search of named accounts within 20 miles of zip code 95035
2.I am trying to insert the contact’s first name when doing an email blast, but it doesn’t seem to be working for me. Have you guys faced a similar problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this via the UI Global Search?  If so you can simply enter the postal code.  However it will search all records, you cannot limit it to within 20 miles of said zip code.
If you are doing it in SOQL, that is a different matter.

Comment: Hi Doug, i need to know how to add the zip code filter so that I can search using Zipcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply enter your Postal Code into the search box like so.

[image: Global Search]

This will do a global search on all Standard and Custom sObjects and display them as lists.  You can then look through the results for the record you want.